# Build Pipeline with Jenkins - M2 Release -> Deployment to JBoss AS

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jboss7.x, continuous-deployment

I am using Jenkins as CI environment and I want to have the ability to deploy the build artifacts directly to a JBoss AS 7.1.1 server. For releasing the Maven artifacts I am using the Jenkins M2 Release Plugin.

The project structure of the project which makes problems looks as follows:

- artifact-parent-pom

  - webapp-module
  - theme-module

The maven goal jboss-as:deploy can only be called on webapp-module.

To deploy the webapp-module to the JBoss server on every build, I added a post-build step calling

> mvn jboss-as:deploy

on the sub-module. This works perfectly for standard SNAPSHOT builds, but not for release builds.

When using the Jenkins M2 Release Plugin to release a new artifact version, the version number is already updated to the next SNAPSHOT-version when the post-build step is executed. I tried to deploy the release version directly at the release step, but this doesn't work, hence the goal jboss-as:deploy cannot be called on the parent-pom.

All Jeknins plugins i have found only support older versions of JBoss like

- Deploy to container Plugin
- JBoss Management Plugin

Is there an easy way to get this working?

Comment: Do you see an error? Just trying to figure out what doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is, that the property project.parent.version is already set to  $MVN_DEV_VERSION and the artifact hasn't been build with this version yet, but is the one to be deployed. Thus the build fails.

Comment: You can use the `filename` property to set the file name if that helps https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html#filename. Not exactly sure how, but it would work if you could get the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. I made two configurations, one for the SNAPSHOTS and one for the RELEASE builds. At the RELEASE build I added two post-steps both calling the goal version:set on the parent-pom but with different properties. This results in the following post-steps:

- mvn newVersion=${MVN_RELEASE_VERSION}
- mvn jboss-as:deploy
- mvn newVersion=${MVN_DEV_VERSION}